# Posicionar imagen en NAVBAR segun resolucion

Tags: reactjs, navbar, position, flex

Tengo 3 div en mi navbar. Cuando la resolucion es para mobiles se muestran solo 1 y quiero que quede centrado. Cuando la resolucion aumenta pasan a ser 2 y cuando aumenta mas pasan a mostrarse los 3. En las dos ultimas res no tengo problemas con la clase d-flex justify-content-between pero no logro centrar el primero en la resolucion mas chica

```
 const Header = () => {
  console.log(window.screen.width);
  return (
    <Navbar>
      <Container className='d-flex justify-content-between'>
        <div>
          <img className='logoCampaña' src={LogoCampaña} alt='logoCampaña' />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2 className='slogan'>Slogan Campaña</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className='logoONG' src={LogoONG} alt='logoONG' />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

[image: img que quiero centrar]
[image: Navbar completa]

Comment: Favor enviar también CSS, tal y como lo enviaste, quedan las 3, solo se ajustan al tamaño de la pantalla, también especificar bien cual es la que deseas que quede centrada cuando solo es una. Debes tener alguna Media Query.

Answer (score 1):

justify-content-evenly distribuye el espacio entre los elementos de manera uniforme(igual entre cada uno)
justify-content-around distribuye el espacio entre los elementos de manera que el espacio entre dos items adyacentes es el mismo, por tanto el espacio vacío anterior al primer item y posterior al último item es la mitad del espacio entre dos items adyacentes.
saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Cambia `justify-content-between`  por `justify-content-evenly`   o sino por
`justify-content-around`.

(texto copiado de otra respuesta del mismo autor desde revisión)

> `justify-content-evenly` distribuye el espacio entre los elementos de
> manera uniforme (igual entre cada uno). `justify-content-around`
> distribuye el espacio entre los elementos de manera que el espacio
> entre dos items adyacentes es el mismo, por tanto el espacio vacío
> anterior al primer item y posterior al último item es la mitad del
> espacio entre dos items adyacentes.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `justify-content-evenly` y `justify-content-around`? ¿Cómo cambiaría usando uno o el otro?